# Get name of generic method inside a proxy class

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I would like to create a proxy class that will be able to retrieve the name of a method given in argument, and an instance of a paramater with generic completion (aka I don't want nameof() or magic strings).

For example, I would like to be able to do something like

```
public interface ITestInterface
{
    void TestMethod(Param myParam) 
}

var proxy = new Proxy<ITestInterface>();
var param = new Param();
proxy.WriteName(x => ITestInterface.TestMethod(param));
```

and the proxy class be able to retrive the name of the method and do a tostring on the instance of the parameter :

```
public class Proxy<T>
{
    public void WriteName(Something something)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(something.MethodName); // write "TestMethod"
        Console.WriteLine(something.Parameter.ToString()); // use the tostring of the instance object
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it would not be easy to support all possible scenarios but for what you have described in the question you can try using [expression trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/):

```
public class Proxy<T>
{
    public void WriteName(Expression<Action<T>> something)
    { 
        // TODO: add correct handling for not supported operations
        if (something.Body is MethodCallExpression mc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(mc.Method.Name);
            foreach (var arg in mc.Arguments)
            {
                if (arg is MemberExpression me && me.Expression is ConstantExpression cnst)
                {
                    var val = me.Member.MemberType switch
                    {
                        MemberTypes.Field => ((FieldInfo)me.Member).GetValue(cnst.Value),
                        MemberTypes.Property => ((PropertyInfo)me.Member).GetValue(cnst.Value),
                        _ => null 
                    };
                    Console.WriteLine(val);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
var proxy = new Proxy<ITestInterface>();
var param = new Param();
proxy.WriteName(t => t.TestMethod(param)); // actually many more can be passed here
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you can try this:

```
public class Proxy<T>
{
    public void WriteName(Expression<Action> action)
    {
        var methodCallExp = (MethodCallExpression)action.Body;

        Console.WriteLine(methodCallExp.Arguments.First().ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(methodCallExp.Method.Name);
    }
}
```

and call proxy class like this:

```
      var proxy = new Proxy<ITestInterface>();
      proxy.WriteName(() => new ConcreteTestInterface().TestMethod(param));
```